# Keep Object Definition with Multi Column Select

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-typing

How can I keep object definition with select, that has more object defined and keep variable from becoming "Any" type? Is it even possible?

I came up with this:

```
DB = DatabaseModel() 

stmt = select(Item, Package).join(Package, Item.Package_id1 == Package.Package_id)
exec = DB.session.execute(stmt).all() # Sequence[Row[Tuple[Item, Package]]]

for row in exec:
    row #Row[Tuple[Item, Package]] 

    Item_object : Item = row[0]   
    Package_object : Package = row[1]
```

This way I just define a value as Object, so I can keep the mapping.
But is there a better (correct) way to do this? Without a need to create new variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was able to come up with answer.
I was not able to unpacked it, because this command:

```
exec = DB.session.execute(stmt).all() 
# Returned type: Sequence[Row[Tuple[Item, Package]]]
```

And so in for loop I cant unpack **typeof(Row)** as I would **typeof(tuple)**.

So correct way to unpack values would be this:

```
DB = DatabaseModel() 

stmt = select(Item, Package).join(Package, Item.Package_id1 == Package.Package_id)
exec = DB.session.execute(stmt).tuples().all() # Sequence[Tuple[Item, Package]]]

for _item, _package in exec:
    .....
```

Adding **.touples()** in execute statements removes **Row** definition and only returns tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `SQLAlchemy 2.0 ORM` style to query objects?

Typing works perfect with this style!

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, sessionmaker,
    selectinload
)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    item_name: Mapped[str]
    package_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("packages.package_id"))
    package: Mapped["Package"] = relationship()


class Package(Base):
    __tablename__ = "packages"
    package_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    package_name: Mapped[str]


engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


with session_maker() as session:
    p1 = Package(package_name="P1")
    i1 = Item(item_name="Item 1", package=p1)
    session.add(p1)
    session.add(i1)
    session.commit()


with session_maker() as session:
    stmt = select(Item)
    # Or with selectinload option to avoid second query
    # stmt = select(Item).options(selectinload(Item.package))
    exec = session.scalars(stmt).all()

    for item in exec:
        print(item)
        print(item.package)
```

Comment: Hi, I am using ORM style to query, but it is my understanding, that scalars functions does not work properly with multiple objects. And where there are more comlex selects witl multiple tables we should use execute